# Proof of cross product integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, surface-integrals, cross-product

I am working through Susan Lea's *Mathematics for Physicists* however I am stuck on problem 31)b):

31) Prove

b)

$\int_{S}(\hat{n}\times\vec{\nabla})\times\vec{u}\hspace{0.5mm}dA = \unicode{x222E}_{C}d\vec{l}\times\vec{u} $

I have looked at the solution and understand that first a differential rectangle is constructed in the x-y plane and the integral on the right is then broken down after applying the cross product. However I get stuck afterwards with how the cross product is computed, I use the determinant method to compute crossproducts for the first row is the x,y,z unit vectors but I believe the next two rows are done incorrectly which is why I don't get the appropriate solution:

[image: The solution]

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Can the downvoter elaborate what issue they found with my post?

Comment: More details, please?  What do you know about $S$, $C$ and $u$?  Is $C$ in the $x$-$y$ plane?

Comment: These are all the details supplied by the problem, I have left nothing out, it is assumed for arbitrary S and C and u. The problem is simplified by assuming the x-y plane. This is a mathematical physics textbook I would like to say that this works for up to 3 dimensions x,y,and z and contour integrals are in the x-y plane. S is a surface integral.

Comment: $C$ is the boundary of $S$? $\hat{n}$ the unit normal to $S$ (in the correct orientation)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is correct

Comment: If $\hat {\mathbf n}$ isn't a constant vector, then there might be some difficulty with the $\nabla(\mathbf u \cdot \hat {\mathbf n})$ term. A different way to write this identity is
$$\int_{\partial S} \mathbf u \times d \mathbf s =
\iint_S ((\nabla \cdot \mathbf u) I - (\nabla \mathbf u)^t) d \mathbf S,$$
where $\nabla \mathbf u$ is the Jacobian matrix, $(\nabla \mathbf u)_{i j} = \partial u_i / \partial x_j$, $I$ is the identity matrix, and the boundary does not have to lie in a plane. Another derivation is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2654912).

Comment: This is a physics case, you should expect $\hat{n}$ to be constant