# Multivariable Calculus Exam Mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

This question was from an exam taken in January 2022 on a course on introductory multivariable calculus and was worded ***exactly*** as follows:

"For a general surface $S$ bounded by a closed curve $C$ show using Stokes theorem that for a vector field, $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})$

$$\int_S\nabla\times(\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S})=\alpha\int_C\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$

and identify the constant $\alpha$."

The "$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$" is used to denote a surface integral and the "$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$" to denote a line integral.

I have asked a couple of mathematicians who work in applied mathematics and they have not been able to prove this either. The LHS is apparently the area of concern - having "$\nabla\times(\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S})$" seems to be what's throwing people off.

I have been told that the answer should result in a vector even though, in the course, vector-valued integrals were never defined and so the notions of "$\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$" and "$\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$" were also not defined, so while I personally believe this question was unfair, I'm asking more about whether or not it's possible.

If this *is* a mistake, could you explain why? And if it isn't, can you prove it?

Comment: I think it is not a mistake. It's extremely close to the question [Proof of cross product integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2898538/26369). I think there's a better question on MathSE for addressing your concerns, but am having trouble finding it right now.

Comment: @MarkS. That does look rather similar. Thank you! Although I think the fact that we have $n\times\nabla$ in the other question makes it different.

Answer (score 3):

It resembles the following vector variant of Stokes' theorem
$$\iint_S(\mathbf{n}\times\nabla)\times \mathbf{F}\,dS=-\int_C\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}.$$
Proof. Note that
$$
(\mathbf{n}\times\nabla)\times \mathbf{F}=
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
n_2\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-n_3\frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
&  
n_3\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-n_1\frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
& 
n_1\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-n_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
F_1 & F_2 &  F_3 
\end{array} \right|
$$
and therefore, by comparing the $x$ components of both sides we find
$$
\begin{align}\left(\iint_S(\mathbf{n}\times\nabla)\times \mathbf{F}\,dS\right)_x
&=\iint_S \left(n_3\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x}-n_1\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}
-n_1\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}+n_2\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}\right)dS\\
&=\iint_S \left(-\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x}\right)\cdot d\mathbf{S}\\
&=\iint_S \left(\nabla \times\left(0,F_3,-F_2\right)\right)\cdot d\mathbf{S}\quad \text{(Stokes' Theorem)}\\
&=\int_C \left(0,F_3,-F_2\right)\cdot d\mathbf{r}\\
&=\left(-\int_C\mathbf{F}\times\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)_x.
\end{align}$$
Similarly we can verfy that the equality holds also for $y$ and $z$ components.

P.S. I wonder if one can play (at least in a formal way) with the [cross-product properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) in order to obtain $\nabla\times(\mathbf{F}\times d\mathbf{S})$:
$$\nabla\times(\mathbf{F}\times d\mathbf{S})=
(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\times d\mathbf{S}+(d\mathbf{S}\times \nabla)\times 
\mathbf{F}=
(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\times d\mathbf{S}+(\mathbf{n}\times \nabla)\times 
\mathbf{F}dS.$$
Note that the term $(\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\times d\mathbf{S}$ is related to a variant of the [divergence theorem](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m317/divVrns.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Of course, this isn't a proof of the question but it makes me think this is what the setter intended. :)

Comment: @Haraganga Yes, the final comment is merely an attempt to give a meaning to your equation. Frankly, I think that the question worded in this way does not make much sense. Is there a website where I can see the course materials?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The course material was uploaded to a private website as pdfs and I think they'd have my guts for garters if I posted that. Trust me when I say nothing like this was even defined in the course.

Comment: @Haraganga Nevermind, I understand...