# Meaning of directional derivative of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a vector field $ \vec{B} (x,y,z)$ then do $ \frac{ \partial B}{ \partial n}$ where n is the direction vector of a line denote the directional derivative of the vector in the direction of $n$?

The reason I ask is that I recently encountered this in a physics textbook but all the gradients and directional derivatives that I've seen till now were defined for scalar fields.

Edit:

The real quantity that I started with was the one from this [mse post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654912/stokes-theorem-for-cross-product-with-line-element):

$$ (\nabla B_i) n_i $$

I thought this would be the directional derivative since it looked like one but then I later realized this is actually a vector field.

A picture from the book:

[image]

Page-158, I.e irodov basic laws of electromagnetism

Comment: Is this helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156880/1257

Comment: I saw that but I don't think I was able to apply the idea from there to this question

Comment: I guess $\tfrac{ \partial B}{ \partial n}(x,y,z)=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\tfrac { \vec{B}((x,y,z)+\Delta tn)- \vec{B}(x,y,z)}{\Delta t}$, that if $B=(B_x,B_y,B_z)$ then 
$\tfrac{ \partial B}{ \partial n}=\left( \tfrac{ \partial B_x}{ \partial n},\tfrac{ \partial B_y}{ \partial n},\tfrac{ \partial B_z}{ \partial n}\right)$.

Comment: I have only seen directional derivatives for scalars, but I will offer a wild guess that what is meant is doing a component-wise directional derivative. That is, treat each component of the vector as a scalar, compute the directional derivative, then combine each result back into a vector. Again, this is only a guess regarding what is meant.

Comment: Can you tell us which textbook you are using? Along with the chapter where you encounter this notation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon done

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer This was the question where I Think I first met you, I finally figured out an intuitive answer and have written it down. So, I guess maybe you could check it out if you wanted to know how this ended up after more than a year

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I've written an answer now

Comment: @Buraian I see! Nice, I'll take a look at it when I can.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a vector field $\vec{B}(x,y,z)$ then do $\frac{\partial\vec B}{\partial n}$ where $n$ is the direction vector of a line denote the directional derivative of the vector in the direction of $n$?

Yes. So is also stated for Force by Dipole in electric field in the same book. Page number 20, I.E. Irodov. Although the author explicitly states that the operation is rather complex and will not be discussed in the book.

The formal definitions can be noted from [here and $\downarrow$](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Directional_derivative).

#### Derivatives of vector-valued functions of vectors:

Let ${\displaystyle \mathbf {f} (\mathbf {v} )}$ be a vector-valued function of the vector ${\displaystyle \mathbf {v} }$ . Then the derivative of ${\displaystyle \mathbf {f} (\mathbf {v} )}$ with respect to ${\displaystyle \mathbf {v} }$  (or at ${\displaystyle \mathbf {v} }$) in the direction ${\displaystyle \mathbf {u} }$ (which maybe $\hat i,\hat j,\hat k$)  is the second-order tensor defined as:

$${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} }{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} =D\mathbf {f} (\mathbf {v} )[\mathbf {u} ]=\left[{\frac {d}{d\alpha }}~\mathbf {f} (\mathbf {v} +\alpha ~\mathbf {u} )\right]_{\alpha =0}}$$
for all vectors ${\displaystyle \mathbf {u} }$ .

Properties:

1. If ${\displaystyle \mathbf {f} (\mathbf {v} )=\mathbf {f} _{1}(\mathbf {v} )+\mathbf {f} _{2}(\mathbf {v} )}$ then ${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} }{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} =\left({\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{1}}{\partial \mathbf {v} }}+{\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{2}}{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\right)\cdot \mathbf {u} .}$
2. If $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{f}_1(\mathbf{v})\times\mathbf{f}_2(\mathbf{v})$ then ${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} }{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} =\left({\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{1}}{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} \right)\times \mathbf {f} _{2}(\mathbf {v} )+\mathbf {f} _{1}(\mathbf {v} )\times \left({\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{2}}{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} \right).}$
3. If $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{f}_1(\mathbf{f}_2(\mathbf{v}))$ then ${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} }{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} ={\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{1}}{\partial \mathbf {f} _{2}}}\cdot \left({\frac {\partial \mathbf {f} _{2}}{\partial \mathbf {v} }}\cdot \mathbf {u} \right).}$

Comment: I was looking for an answer which explained the properties a bit more / a geometric description

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it intuitive in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you can easily extrapolate to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In cartesian coordinates you can write the direction vector $\vec{e_r}$ from the origin to a point in a circunference of radius $1$. Direction vectors are unit vectors.

$$\vec{e_r} = \cos(\theta)\vec{e_x} + \sin(\theta)\vec{e_y}$$

Recall that $\vec{e_x}$ and $\vec{e_y}$ are fixed in our coordinates, so they will not be affected by the derivative, but $\theta$ do. Generally, in real life problems, $\theta$ changes over implicit time $t$ such that $\theta(t)$. With this in mind we can now take the derivative of the vector $\vec{e_r}$:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e_r} = \frac{d}{d\theta}\cos(\theta)\vec{e_x} + \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin(\theta)\vec{e_y}$$
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e_r} = (-\sin(\theta)\vec{e_x} + cos(\theta)\vec{e_y})\frac{d}{d\theta}\theta$$

Can you see that they are perpendicular to each other? In fact we can prove it with the dot product:

$$\vec{e_r} \cdot \frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e_r} = -\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 0$$

Geometrically, why are they perpendicular? Consider the vector $\vec{e_r}$ for some $\theta$. It changes with infinitesimal $d\theta$ to a new position of $\theta$, say, $\vec{e_r}(\theta + d\theta)$. Note that **in the limit** $\vec{e_r}(\theta + d\theta) -\vec{e_r}(\theta)$ is a vector perpendicular to $\vec{e_r}(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359170/688539) is the general meaning of gradient of vector field, here we take the directioncal derivative of this gradient.

However, I'll give a standalone interpretation:

When we do the derivative of $B$ field in the normal direction, we take consider a point in space, and move in the direction of the normal of the loop. Here it looks like along the z-axis, we see take the difference between the vector we get after moving along the z-axis a teeny bit and the original vector. This gives us a vector difference, dividing this difference vector by the amount of distance we moved in space gives the required value.

So, since we talk about vector difference $\frac{dB}{dn}$ is infact a vector again.

Comment: Right, this is perhaps the best way of saying it, +1. I've also struggled to understand the normal derivative, particularly when it comes to Green's theorem and the likes , but I feel a whole lot more comfortable about it now.

Comment: If you have time, go check this book Geometric Calculus by Alan Macdonald. Also, the Leo Dorst Geometric algebra book. I'm still learning, but from my understanding, it brings all this vector stuff, complex number stuff, quaternion etc etc together into one single thing @SarveshRavichandranIyer